# How do I bash a command from some x program with python, that can be only bashed with terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I want to run a specific command from a package that can be only run from terminal, through an executable python script. I have already tried subprocess.Popen(). Running the python script from terminal solves the problem but i want the final script to be able to run with just double clicks(i.e. executable file)

Comment: are you looking for something like this: [tutorial](https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi) ?

Comment: No!! I am looking for something that will allow me to use python to run a command made to be run strictly under terminal.